# Having trouble with finishing up proving 'If $z = z0$ is a zero of order $n$ of $f(z)$, then it is a zero of order $2n$ of $(f(z))^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Since $z = z$<sub>$0$</sub> is a zero of order $n$ of $f(z)$, we have

- $f(z)$ = $(z-z$<sub>$0$</sub>$)^np(z)$

where $p(z)$ is analytic at $z= z$<sub>$0$</sub> and $p(z$<sub>$0$</sub>) ≠ $0$.

It follows that,

- $(f(z))^2$ = $(z-z$<sub>$0$</sub>$)^{2n}(p(z))^2$

At this point, $z = z$<sub>$0$</sub> would be a zero of order $2n$ of $(f(z))^2$ if $(p(z))^2$ is analytic at $z= z$<sub>$0$</sub> and $p(z$<sub>$0$</sub>) ≠ $0$ but I'm not quite seeing how to prove this last thing exactly.

Any tips?

Edit: I guess a product of 2 non-zero terms would still be non-zero, and also a product of 2 analytic functions is still analytic but how do you prove this?

Comment: The product of analytic functions is analytic.

Comment: @lcv Yes you're right, I was overthinking it by thinking I had to formally prove that. Thanks